# triming a string

Tags: php, char, trim

This may be dumb but I've been beating my head against it for a bit now..

$values contains this text:

```
'58','val','val','val','2011-05-12 21-41-42','','0','micahstesttest',
```

Why won't this trim the last comma?

```
trim($values, ",");
```

EDIT - this is how $values is being generated:

```
$values = "";
foreach($users_table as $k=>$v){ $values .= "'$v',"; }
trim($values, ",");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I caved.

```
$values = preg_replace("/,$/", "", $values);
```

If anyone knows what I was doing wrong, I'd love to hear it though.  It's got me stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that there's extra whitespace after the end of your string? Trying printing it surrounded with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
<?php
$str = "'58','val','val','val','2011-05-12 21-41-42','','0','micahstesttest',";
echo( trim($str, ","));

?>
```

you could also do this

```
echo( trim(trim($str, " "),","));
```

or

```
echo(trim($str, ", "));
```

if you just want to put the values of an array in to a new array just use  [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$values = array_values($users_table);
echo($values);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem possible for this string to have any trailing whitespace (see my edit to the original post).  But I tried this to be on the safe side and didn't have any luck.

Comment: @sing1ejack I edited my answer let me know if that does what you need

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some extra character after last comma `,`. See this code:

```
$str = "'58','val','val','val','2011-05-12 21-41-42','','0','micahstesttest', ";
var_dump(trim($str, " "));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(69) "'58','val','val','val','2011-05-12 21-41-42','','0','micahstesttest',"
```

Try checking your original string with `var_dump` like this:

```
var_dump($str);
```